# Secure Delete of eMMC Card (BLKSECDISCARD returns EOPNOTSUPP)

Tags: security, linux-device-driver, sd-card, erase

I need to securely erase an MMC card in an embedded system.  However, my `ioctl(BLKSECDISCARD)` returns `EOPNOTSUPP`, (as does `BLKDISCARD`).

By reading kernel code, the MMC driver enables DISCARD by setting `QUEUE_FLAG_DISCARD` in `kernel/linux/drivers/mmc/card/queue.c mmc_queue_setup_discard()`, which is called as follows:

```
if (mmc_can_erase(card))
    mmc_queue_setup_discard(mq->queue, card);
```

Where `mmc_can_erase()` is defined in `kernel/linux/drivers/mmc/core/core.c` as:

```
int mmc_can_erase(struct mmc_card *card)
{
    if ((card->host->caps & MMC_CAP_ERASE) &&
        (card->csd.cmdclass & CCC_ERASE) && card->erase_size)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

What is required for the conditions in `mmc_can_erase()` to be met?

Is it a feature of the card, the controller, the driver, the way the kernel is built, or something else?

Ideally, I'd like to enable the `BLKSECDISCARD` feature, but am unsure what I need to do, or even if it is possible on my embedded system.  Can it be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`card->host->caps` describes the capabilities of the host controller. Where this is set (assuming it is supported) depends on which controller you're using, for example for the SDHCI controller its set in [`sdhci_setup_host()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.8/source/drivers/mmc/host/sdhci.c#L3234).

`card->csd.cmdclass` is read from the card's CSD (Card/Device Specific Data), and indicates which classes of commands the card supports. In this case the code is checking for the erase class of commands. See [`mmc_decode_csd()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.8/source/drivers/mmc/core/mmc.c#L168).

`card->erase_size` is also read from the card's CSD (or the extended CSD if the card has one), and is set in [`mmc_set_erase_size()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.8/source/drivers/mmc/core/mmc.c#L128).

None of these depend on how the kernel is built, but the capabilities of your hardware. To find out which one(s) are preventing you using secure erase you will need to add some instrumentation to your kernel to print the values of these fields.

Comment: According to comments I've seen, no USB card reader supports this feature. If you need to have something like Raspberry Pi which has card reader on the motherboard to be able to issue the command to execute secure erase.